# Reference on abuse of stimulant medications among professors to enhance academic performance?

Tags: professorship, reference-request, health, drugs

Various research articles<sup>1</sup> have been published on the prevalence of stimulant medicine (Adderall, Concerta, Ritalin) abuse among undergraduate students.

By "abuse of stimulant medicine," I am referring to the practice of students taking prescription medication that is prescribed to someone else (or, that is prescribed to them under false pretenses) in order to improve their focus and concentration while studying.

There is some [anecdotal evidence](http://www.cbsnews.com/news/popping-pills-a-popular-way-to-boost-brain-power/) of university faculty taking Adderall and related medications to enhance academic performance (and *not* to treat an attention disorder).

Is there any reference to research<sup>2</sup> on the prevalance of stimulant medicine abuse among university faculty?

---

<sup>1</sup> Here is a review article that covers some of them:

> Varga, Matthew D. "Adderall abuse on college campuses: a comprehensive literature review." *Journal of evidence-based social work* 9.3 (2012): 293-313.
>   DOI: [10.1080/15433714.2010.525402](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/15433714.2010.525402)

<sup>2</sup> I am looking for answers that are a reference to such a study. I am not looking for answers from anecdotal evidence not supported by a study or citation. I am also not looking for answers explaining why such a study is unlikely to exist, or why it should not be trusted if it did.

Comment: Paul Erdős was a frequent amphetamine user (read Ron Graham's biography of Erdős, "[The Man Who Loved Only Numbers](http://www.amazon.com/The-Man-Loved-Only-Numbers/dp/0786884061)" for an interesting story about that).

Comment: And remember what Erdos said about the impact on mathematics of him being clean for a month. :-)

Comment: I've always wondered - if indeed there are drugs which generally enhance performance (as opposed to removing a deficit such as ADD) at the research level, given the strong competitive pressure and the large number of brilliant academics we should expect that **almost all** of the top researchers are drug abusers, since those that abuse naturally rise above those that refuse to. You could argue by pointing out rampant abuse among students, but students are not rational (incidentally, the abuse is not correlated with success AFAIK), nor are is exam equivalent to general research ability.

Comment: William Halsted had a long history of abusing cocaine (which is a stimulant) and morphine (which is not).

Comment: @Superbest There are no drugs that enhance general intellectual performance. Any drugs taken would be to enhance or modify some specific aspect at the cost of some other aspect (such as LSD, giving you creativity while removing logical thought), or to correct an existing, known imbalance such as ADD. However, the efficacy of these drugs is not related to the question of whether people abuse them. And taking enough of a drug will create the imbalance that the drug will then correct (i.e. caffeine dependency).

Comment: @Feij I don't know on what authority you assert that there are no such drugs, but that aside, I think efficacy is very relevant. As I explained, existence of effective performance enhancing drugs leads to testable predictions about demographics of abuse (ie. the top level). It is much easier to decide whether all top researchers abuse drugs than whether a small minority of all researchers abuses them.

Comment: I find it noteworthy when Googling something reasonably meaningful returns nothing. This is the case with "stimulant use among faculty".

You probably would have to dig in at the university library and do systematic digging through publication and thesis databases (UMI/ProQuest etc.) and play with keywords to get anything at all.

I would suggest expanding search to any adult professionals (doctors, lawyers etc.) to get some hits that are categorically closer to professors (as working professionals, as opposed to students).

Comment: As for reasons for lack of research:

One is probably that so much attention is focused on stimulant use among students and that use probably outpaces the like among faculty in terms of pure numbers (a lot more students than faculty out there!) that it renders research on the latter an afterthought.

Another likely reason is that faculty probably resort to "relaxants" (i.e. alcohol, marijuana) rather than "stimulants" because, unlike students, there is less need for them to be extremely focused for very short periods of time like a 2-hour test or an all-nighter cramming session.

Comment: I would think that alcohol abuse among faculty would be a more relevant/worthwhile research topic, due to significantly higher incidence rates and more dire consequences (addiction etc.).

No matter how loaded, faculty schedules are probably more forgiving in terms of greater latitude in deadlines and ability to manage time effectively. Nevertheless, interesting question and I'd be curious what you dig up.

Comment: @Aymor I appreciate the comments. Thanks :) I agree that this research is not exactly low-hanging fruit. Hopefully even if there isn't a "real" answer now, there will be sometime in the future - and someone can post it then.

Comment: Agreed. ^? Maybe there is a niche there. In the meantime you could do some looking and maybe answer your own q, or state more explicitly in the question what literature research you have or have not done up to now. This will improve the respondent's understanding of what is needed of them beyond what's been already done.

Comment: I suspect that it might be better to phrase this question as asking about "use of stimulants", not "abuse of stimulants".  "abuse" carries a value judgement that is not relevant here; it seems irrelevant to your question whether use of stimulants is good or bad.

Comment: @D.W. I explain in the answer what I mean by "abuse" - taking prescription medication that is prescribed to someone else or prescribed under false pretenses. It's a [standard meaning](http://teens.drugabuse.gov/drug-facts/prescription-drugs) of the word "abuse" in the context of prescription medications. Stimulant "use" would include those who take medicine prescribed to them by a doctor after an honest accounting of symptoms.

Comment: @Superbest _but students are not rational_ — And faculty are??

Comment: Why would university researchers rat on each other about drug use? I think that is why there isn't more research.

Comment: @JeffE Faculty are more rational. Think many-valued logic.

Comment: If you are experimenting with stimulants you might have to stop. Watch your symptoms! And call your doctor if you get insomnia.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There were several prominent publications in Nature, spurred by a survey that they conducted of their readers who were able to broadly identify their area of work.  See this link here for information about the survey, which also cites the papers that were published in Nature.  http://network.nature.com/groups/naturenewsandopinion/forum/topics/1309

In researching this topic, I used google scholar and the search terms "stress stimulants faculty -students" and published 2008 or later to arrive at meaningful search results.

The most likely reason there is more work published on student use is that students as a demographic group are both easier to study and are a more similar group of cohorts than faculty as a demographic group, which are more diverse in age, race, ethnicity, etc.

Comment: Thanks, this is a great find! I added [another answer with more details](http://academia.stackexchange.com/a/37050/11365) based on the link you gave.

Answer (score 7):

This is a more detailed answer explaining the results of the survey given by [Sydney E. Everhart's answer](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/36884/11365).

The results of the informal 2008 Nature survey<sup>1</sup> found that

> One in five respondents said they had used drugs for non-medical reasons to stimulate their focus, concentration or memory.

More specifically, a [comment](http://network.nature.com/groups/naturenewsandopinion/forum/topics/1309?page=1#reply-3604) attributed to the author of this article clarifies:

> For the record, our poll didn’t parse out academics, or practicing scientists very thoroughly and the overall results can’t really be tied to scientists exactly. But our demographics do allow us to make some assumptions. We asked what category generally describes your field and included among the limited choices, Biology, Chemistry, Earth & Environmental Science, Engineering, Medicine, Physics, and Education. So if we assume those are ‘academic’ fields and academic respondents, we have 817 respondents out of a total 1,400 that fit that loose demographic. Of those we found that 106 (13%) used neuroenhancing-type drugs for medically prescribed reasons. And 159 (19%) used drugs for non-medical (i.e. cognition-enhancing) purposes. That’s pretty consistent with the overall distribution in the poll.

Unfortunately, the data from that survey - which was previously freely available for download - seems to no longer be online.

---

<sup>1</sup> Maher, Brendan. "Poll results: look who's doping." Nature 452 (2008): 674-675. DOI: [10.1038/452674a](http://dx.doi.org/10.1038/452674a)