# How rampant are "smart drugs" in academia?

Tags: productivity

Is it common for people in academia to use "smart drugs"/prescription medications to help them be more productive? Or do most people just use things like caffeine to be more productive?

Comment: My hay-fever medication also makes me more productive.

Comment: Quantum mechanics problem sets often required a beer or two back in the day...

Comment: The answer to this question surely varies widely by country, academic institutions, seniority level, etc. - quite difficult to give a general answer. I think the best you can hope for references to some articles on the matter.

Comment: @JonCuster They still do, Jon. :)

Comment: Are you asking about professors in research? Or undergrad freshmen student freaking out about finals?

Comment: Mathematicians take coffee...

Comment: I enjoy a glass or four of Sauv Blanc.

Comment: Cocktails help with grading papers, but it has some side-effects in terms of error rate and getting up early the next morning. Caffeine is as close to universal of a "performance enhancing drug" as there is, from coffee and tea to supplements and "sports drinks". Sometimes there is a funny smelling smoke near the library, but I'm skeptical of whether or not that might actually "improve" academic performance. And I doubt very many conference papers were completed without the assistance of at least a mild sugar high. This is all to say...I think you are going to need to be more specific.

Comment: [This informal survey by *Nature* in 2008](http://www.nature.com/news/2008/080409/full/452674a.html) found "large-scale use" of cognition-enhancing drugs by their readers.

Comment: Related: http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/29318/reference-on-abuse-of-stimulant-medications-among-professors-to-enhance-academic